# Fluid layout with an inputbox and button, how to solve it?

Tags: html, css, button, fluid-layout, inputbox

I have a problem with a responsive design using the responsive formula for %. It workes great but not for a search bar, its just an inputbox and a button thats display: inline. It seems like there is an gap between them without me putting in any margin or padding, and that is why the formula dosen't work.. But thats my guess, can anyone tell me how to solve it? Now when I put the % in it scales, but after a while the button jumps down..

My HTML:

```
<div id="searchWrapper">

 <input type="search" id="inputSearch2">
 <button id="buttonSearch2">Sök</button>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#searchWrapper{
background-color: #854242;
width: 100%;
display: inline;
}

#inputSearch2, #buttonSearch2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#inputSearch2{
    width: 52.08333333333333%; /* 500px / 960px */
    margin-left: 2.60416666666667%; /* 25px / 960px */
    margin-right: ;
}

#buttonSearch2{
    width: 41.66666666666667%; /* 400px / 960px */
    margin-right: 2.60416666666667%; /* 25px / 960px */
}
```

For the hole site i uploaded it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lbkg/

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what your wanting. As for your button moving down.. If you apply a
min-width: some%;  or min-width: somepx;  it wont move down on you when your scaling to a smaller resolution.

Comment: What i want is a fluid layout, thats truly responsive. So the formula of taking the object devided with the width of what its in. Like here the input box is 500px and the wrapper is 960px so 500/960 = 52.08333333333333%. wich should scale pefectly whatever size the window is..

Comment: and I have to do that to the inpubox, paddings and button.. It should work but it dosent, and I think its because there is a gap between the inputbox and the button, without me putting in any margin or padding.. So I need help to fix so it works. I dont know if you can take away the gap between or whats possible to do, but i dont know how to solve it and thats what I need help with =)

Answer (score 0):

if you want your design to be responsive, you need to change all of your widths, margins, and paddings to EM or % (percent will be fine in this case).  remember each element should have a total of width + padding + margin = 100%, and the 100% is 100% of the width of the parent element.

Comment: Yes I know, Im on my way.. but this part dosent work with the fluid layout formula.. so I need help to fix that part? :)

Comment: im so sorry, you did say that in your question! i had good results using inline-flex as the display for #searchWrapper : #searchWrapper{
 background-color: #854242;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-flex;
 }

Comment: documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes & http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-flex.asp ... note this is not supported by IE9 & earlier (ugh IE always ruins everything for front-end development!!! >: )

Comment: I got some help from my teacher, I dont remember now but it was something in the code messing it up.. But its fixed at least =)